# C# WebClient can not upload large files

Tags: c#, php

I have a large file (500MB) and my application can not send it to my webpage.

```
public static void UploadFile(string url, string fileName) {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] responseBinary = client.UploadFile(url, fileName);
    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary);
    MessageBox.Show(response);
}
```

It sends to a php file. I tried a check

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

but both of them is empty.
When I try to upload a small file (8KB) it is in $_FILES['file'].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your web server reject large files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify your server's `php.ini` file to allow big files to be sent to it, those are the two directives you have to modify:

```
upload_max_filesize = 900M
post_max_size = 900M
```

Also, remember to restart apache or nginx or whatever is your server after you edited the `php.ini` file.

**EDIT**

If you don't have access to this kind of configuration on your host, you could try (it may, or may not be allowed) modifing this settings at `.htaccess` file (on the root of your site) adding the following to it:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 900M
php_value post_max_size 900M
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about it.
I just thought that server dropped the connection and tried max_execution_time